Android HorizontalPager block scrolling
I have an HorizontalPager. Is it somehow possible to block scrolling forward or backward?
Fore example I have a boolean value. If this is true, scrolling forward should be not possible. Just scrolling backward.
I need this for an introduction page on first app start. and one page needs to be accepted or declined. so therefore it should not be possible to scroll forward on this specific page without clicking the accept Button
val canScrollForward = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

HorizontalPager(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color.Red),
            state = pagerState
        ) {


It's hard to imagine how this would would not seriously annoy the user. The expectation is that when you can scroll in one direction that you can also scroll back. Breaking that expected behavior doesn't sound like a great idea. If you instead just want certain pages not to be accessible then just remove them from the pager.

I need this for an introduction page on first app start. and one page needs to be accepted or declined. so therefore it should not be posdible to scroll forward on this specific page without clicking the accept Button
